# Return initializer list from local variable by value

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

I'm getting free(): invalid size when trying to do something like below:

```
std::u32string FileMappingWrapper::getCurrCharPosAsString() const
{
    std::u32string progressString;
    size_t currLine = getFrameStartPos();
    while (currLine)
    {
        progressString.push_back(U'0' + currLine % 10);
        currLine /= 10;
    }
    return {progressString.rbegin(), progressString.rend()}; <- I expect that std::u32string rvalue constructor or RVO will be used
}
```

Then I call this functions from other one:

```
void CurrFrameVisitor::visit(windows::NCursesProgressWindowDecorator *window)
{
    RawWindowBuffer newBuffer(window->getWindowDimensions().first, window->getWindowDimensions().second);
    auto progress = window->getParentWindowHandler()->getFileMapper()->getPrintedProgress();
    auto lineNo = window->getParentWindowHandler()->getFileMapper()->getCurrCharPosAsString();
    std::copy(progress.begin(), progress.end(), newBuffer[0].begin());
    newBuffer[0][progress.size()] = '%';
    if (lineNo.empty()) {
        lineNo.push_back(U'0');
    }
    std::copy(lineNo.begin(), lineNo.end(), std::next(newBuffer[0].begin(), progress.size() + 2));
    window->print(std::move(newBuffer)); <- All is good untill this point
}
```

I know the example cannot be compiled, but here is the thing I debugged the code and I can see that when calling visitor all is good, until stack unwinding. Trying to destroy variable created from initializer list `auto lineNo = window->getParentWindowHandler()->getFileMapper()->getCurrCharPosAsString();` raises SIGABRT. So my question is: Is retuning initializer list by value from local object like I did safe and valid? Thanks

Update:

This is the error was due to not big enough newBuffer array. Why then gdb tells that SIGABORT is when destroying lineNo object? Output from gdb:

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff6c07801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff6c50897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff6d7db9a "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff6c5790a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff6d7bda0 "free(): invalid size") at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x00007ffff6c5ee2c in _int_free (have_lock=0, p=0x7fffec000dd0, av=0x7ffff6fb2c40 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4161
#5  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x7fffec000de0) at malloc.c:3124
#6  0x000055555556b05e in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char32_t>::deallocate (this=<optimized out>, __p=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:125
#7  std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char32_t> >::deallocate (__a=..., __n=<optimized out>, __p=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:462
#8  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t, std::char_traits<char32_t>, std::allocator<char32_t> >::_M_destroy (__size=<optimized out>, this=0x7ffff68274a0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:226
#9  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t, std::char_traits<char32_t>, std::allocator<char32_t> >::_M_dispose (this=0x7ffff68274a0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:221
#10 std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t, std::char_traits<char32_t>, std::allocator<char32_t> >::~basic_string (this=0x7ffff68274a0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:647
#11 mirror::printer::CurrFrameVisitor::visit (this=<optimized out>, window=0x5555557c8040) at src/printer/CurrFrameVisitor.cpp:23 <- this is the line  auto lineNo = window->getParentWindowHandler()->getFileMapper()->getCurrCharPosAsString();
```

Comment: I doubt that `return` line is the problem. Are you sure `newBuffer[0]` is large enough for your two `std::copy` calls?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was confused by gdb output. Do you know maybe why it behaves like I descibed in update? Why GDB tells me sigabort when destroying the object I mentioned? Also please post your anserr I will accept it.

Comment: As an aside, it's inefficient to construct a reversed copy to return. `std::reverse()` and return the local instead. Also, should a frame-start-position of `0` really result in an empty string?

Comment: If you stomp past the declared local variables you can destroy the information the processor uses to return from function calls. All this information is held on the stack, so can be quite vulnerable.